# Analyse de « tu viendras me voir »

Tags: verbes

Je me demande comment on pourrait analyser le groupe « me voir » dans la phrase « tu viendras me voir demain ».

Venir étant intransitif, ce ne peut être un Cod (?).

Comment: Le groupe « me voir » est complément circonstanciel de but  (répond à la question Tu viendras pourquoi ?  dans quel but?   Dans le groupe « me voir » « me » est COD de voir.

Answer (score 2):

Le groupe « **me voir** » est complément circonstanciel de but. Il répond à la question :

> Tu viendras pourquoi ? dans quel but ?

Dans le groupe « **me voir** », « **me** » est COD de voir.